# pyspark.pandas - type Series doesn't define __round__ method

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I have a Spark DF that I've converted to a pySpark Pandas DF using `df.to_pandas_on_spark()`.

I have some logic that rounds a column i.e:

```
 df[Column_Name] = round(df[Income] - df[Fees],2)
```

but get the following error

> TypeError: type Series doesn't define **round** method

After searching around it seems like historically (with Koalas) the fix was to use pySpark's SQL functions:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df[Column_Name] = f.round(df[Income] - df[Fees],2)
```

Is there no `import pyspark.pandas` `round` function equivalent???

Because when I use `pyspark.sql.functions` `round` I get the following error:

> Invalid argument, not a string or column: 57    0.000000

Not sure why it gives me a "not a string" error, do people round strings? I would expect at the very least it outputted "not a float/int/number etc..."

All of this logic works fine when I'm using solely `Pandas` (not to confuse this with `pySpark.Pandas`).

Comment: What is the schema for the two columns ?